# Aggregate initialization with dependent member initializer, instanciated in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization

The title is almost as long as the minimal code producing the error on Visual Studio (tested on both 2017 and 2019):

```
#include <string>

struct Foo
{   
    std::string a;
    std::string b{"prefix_" + a};
};


int main()
{
    std::string str{"some string"};
    Foo i{str};

    [str]()
    {
        Foo j{str};
    };
}
```

On GCC and Clang, both instantiation of `Foo` are okay (local to main, and local to lambda)
On Visual Studio, the instantiation in lambda leads to the error:

```
error C2326: 'auto main::<lambda_a25bbcbd3e2dc2b2209cfbdd50a2113b>::operator ()(void) const': function cannot access 'j'
```

If `Foo::b` has a member initializer that does not depend on another member of `Foo`, there is no error. I suspect this is why the error mention accessing `j` (reading `j.a` to initialize `j.b`).

Is this behaviour standard conformant, or is this a bug in Visual Studio frontend?

PS: The Godbolt example https://godbolt.org/z/68zbYx

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug in MSVC++. If you had `Foo j{str};` outside the lambda there's no compiler error. It doesn't make sense.